# Clickatell 2 way messaging- not receiving inbound sms

Tags: clickatell

I'm reviving our organisations clickatell account

was set up years ago, so the api managment is in their developer central platform rather than the main portal

I can send SMS's out from Civi
And as a recipient I can text back *yay*

But, although the recieved messages are showing in my clickatell account, they are not showing as inbound sms in Civi *boo*

2 way settings for the long number are
[image: screenshot of 2 way settings for clickatell long number]

I can't find further instructions on this, and can't figure which step I've missed.

Do I need to add a target username and password into these settings?
The current civi documentation doesn't mention them, so initially left these fields blank.
Have tried with the API user name and password, and with a civicrm username and password.
All send fine, and all reply texts show as recieved in the clickatell reports
[image: screenshot-clickatell-message-report]
Nothing showing in Civi.

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Are the replies showing up as new contacts? - this happens if Civi can't match the reply to a contact. For Twilio you have to use the full international number when sending the SMS,  because that's what Twilio will use in the reply. If you use the 07xx format when sending the replies create new contacts because there is no match

Comment: That's the info I needed to know Andy!- Thank you

How are you managing the collection of new mobile numbers so that they are recorded in the right format

Comment: I'll make this the answer..  The users have been told to use the full international format, there's no system change we've made to enforce that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the replies showing up as new contacts? - this happens if Civi can't match the reply to a contact. For Twilio you have to use the full international number when sending the SMS, because that's what Twilio will use in the reply. If you use the 07xx format when sending the replies create new contacts because there is no match

Comment: Yup. Sent the original message to a contact in civi that started 07xxxx

(Had set clickatell to adjust outgoing numbers to swap 0 for 44)

Searched for "Inbound SMS" activity and found all replies going to a new nameless contact with mobile number only.

Adjusting client record so that sms number started 44 saw Inbound SMS activities show on contact record